# add all rows containing HH:MM stored as string in android database

Tags: android

I want to add HH:MM format into total time in same format but I have stored this time format in android database as string so I don't know how to retrieve it.
So please help me if any query is there related to the same.

Suppose 15:40 and 12:20 are two fields stored as strings in my table and I want to add the whole column and want to get 28:00 as output.

Comment: show your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array like:

```
String[] timesArr = new String[]{"12:30", "10:10", "11:05", "2:50"};
```

then you can use this:

```
public String addTimes(String[] times) {
    int hours = 0;
    int mins = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        String[] ar = times[i].split(":");
        hours += Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
        mins += Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
    }
    hours+= (mins / 60);
    mins = (mins % 60);

    return hours + ":" + mins;
}
```

and call it:

```
addTimes(timesArr)
```

it will return the sum of times.

Comment: but my values are stored in android database

Comment: I suppose you have a helper class to retrieve data from a database in the form of a cursor. Loop through this cursor instead of the array and get your result.